# Transforming dates using SSIS derived Column

Tags: ssis, etl

In my SSIS Project some records of the date column when retrieved they get distorted as in 2012 turns into 0212 but this doesn't happen to all records, so I tried to write a derived column expression that detects if the year starts with 0 replaces that 0 with the second character of the year.

This is my code
`ISNUll(column) ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DATEPART("yyyy", column < 1000 ? (DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,4) YEAR(column), 1, 1) + "0" + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,4) YEAR(column), 3, 2) + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,10) column, 3, 8)) : COLUMN)`

but the code returns the error Conditional Operation Failed
Why?

Comment: At a minimum, column names are case sensitive. In your sample code, you mix `column` and `COLUMN`